# VS code Java CheckStyle extension not responding

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, checkstyle

I'm working on a Maven Java project in VScode and I would like to use https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting to format and auto-correct the checkstyle errors in the source code.

I installed the extension, from command-pallet configured google_checks.xml, set checkstyle version, and then tried to trigger it from the command-palet with 'check code with checkstyle' command.

Nothing happened...

My settings.json looks as follows:

```
{
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "java.checkstyle.configuration": "/google_checks.xml",
    "java.checkstyle.version": "8.43"
}
```

**[EDIT]**
My pom.xml is:

```xml
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <configLocation>sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>checkstyle</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I forgot to mention that it's a Maven project. I activated the Maven site command, I saw 273 errors reported, then configured the extension to sun_check.xml as well but again no result when I tried to use it.

What's missing in order to trigger this extension?

Comment: Can you post your code if convenient?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a version mismatch "java.checkstyle.version" was configured to "8.43", when I changed it to "8.18" it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the tutorial: installing **Checkstyle for Java**, setting configuration file, then the configuration is applied to .java file immediately:
[image]

Deleting the generated settings about checkstyle, opening Command Palette and choose the option **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**, then try again. OR please refer to [goole_checks.xml](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) and check if your code has already met the rules.

Comment: I tried to clean the server workspace but I get no results again. I made directed 'checkstyle' errors so my source code doesn't meet the rules. Any idea?